# Trouble with importing pyplot from matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-import

This program currently does not work

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('trial.jpg',0)
plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  # to hide tick values on X and Y axis
plt.show()
```

I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Karl\Desktop\Python\OpenCV\matplotlib.py", line 4, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\Karl\Desktop\Python\OpenCV\matplotlib.py", line 4, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ImportError: cannot import name 'pyplot'
```

But when I type in each line of that code in the I.E. (using IDLE)... it works?
Why would this be. It seems to be when executing all of this code at once it fails, but for some reason not when I type it individually into the interactive environment.

Comment: Clearly matplotlib is installed into the correct directory(it is, I checked) because all of these lines of code execute individually. Also, even when I try this through the command line it doesn't work, indicating it is not just an IDLE issue.

Comment: Do you have a directory called "matplotlib"
in your current working directory with blank
init.py file in it?

Comment: ...or is your script called `matplotlib.py`? If yes, rename it to something else, maybe `matplotlib_test.py`.

Comment: When you are a beginner (and probably an experienced programmer as well), all your program names should start with 'my', e.g.`my_matplotlib1.py`

Comment: All of you are correct, and I will apply this to every future program. I am embarrassed that I made this mistake but learned a good bit in "figuring it out"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling scripts or python from directory,
and importing matplotlib, it will check if any directory named `matplolib` is there in your current working directory first, rather than
the install of matplotlib.

Assuming that you have `matplotlib` directory in your working directory with a blank `init` file, when you do the following:

```
import matplotlib 
print matplotlib.__version__
```

It shows you that `'module' object has no attribute '__version__'`.

And   `print  matplotlib.__file__` gives you `matplotlib/__init__.pyc`.

There is **no pyplot** in this directory. Hence, you got your error.

**Solution**: 
 Rename or delete this directory or if you don't want to rename or delete, move it to any other directory from the current working directory.